# How to use the list the member detail AND order date by user input using WHERE condition?

Tags: oracle11g

I want to show the member detail by input member id then input order date greater than current date SO
I can list the all member detail but after AND condition,
it give me following error: 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

```
SELECT G_MEMBER.MEMBER_ADDRESS, 
G_ORDER.PAYMENT_TYPE,G_ORDER.ORDER_DATE,G_ALBUM.ALBUM_NAME
FROM G_MEMBER
INNER JOIN G_ORDER
ON G_MEMBER.MEMBER_ID = G_ORDER.MEMBER_ID
INNER JOIN G_ALBUM
ON G_MEMBER.MEMBER_ID = G_MEMBER.MEMBER_ID
WHERE G_MEMBER.MEMBER_ID= '&MEMBER_ID'
AND G_ORDER.ORDER_DATE='&ENTER_DATE' > CURRENT_DATE; code here
```

Comment: @Strawberry Oracle

Comment: I see an issue in `G_ORDER.ORDER_DATE='&ENTER_DATE' > CURRENT_DATE`. What should this do?

Comment: @Aleksej I want to pop up then let user input the date, then the input date greater than current_date, so it will list down the member detail and date that's greater than the date by user input

Comment: So you need `'&ENTER_DATE' > CURRENT_DATE`; why the equal? Also, you are treating strings as dates, and this is not a good idea; what is the type of the column `ORDER_DATE`?

Comment: Yup, I need '&ENTER_DATE' > CURRENT_DATE;  because I want to list the SELECT order detail after current date.
I using this type "TO_DATE('2017/05/17','YYYY/MM/DD') " for  ORDER_DATE.